# Getting different count values if i run a query with more than maximum value of column value

Tags: php, mysql

Today I've encountered a new issue in MySQL.

When I've executed the following query

```
select `column` from table where `column` between '1' and '30000'
```

I've got three results

```
234
123
111
```

and when I've executed same query with different value

```
select `column` from table where `column` between '1' and '9000'
```

I've got six results

```
111
123
343
234
765
568
```

What could be the issue?

FYI : Datatype of the column is varchar.

Comment: datatype is varchar and you are trying to find values between to numbers, How it is possible. Convert that column to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you try to select on a text based field in a numeric way. If you would change your field to a integer field you'll get the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, the issue is that the column `column` is not of data type numeric, it is varchar or string.